# Unable to read text field value if HTMl doesn't have value

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read text value but unable read because of in HTML doesn't have value , i am attaching HTML plz take a look into this and suggest how to read text value.

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td class="letter">A.</td>
    <!---->
    <td class="one">Length<input min="0" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode == 32 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 46" step="1" type="text" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched"> ft</td>
    <!---->
    <td class="two"><input max="11" min="0" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57) || event.charCode == 32 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 46" step="1" type="text" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid"> in</td>
```

After inspecting element that value are not present on the HTML.

Comment: Which text value are you trying to read `Length` or `ft` or `in`

Comment: I am trying to read both value ft and in

Comment: Additionally, you need to provide the _HTML_ once the _text_ fields are populated with proper values for `ft` and `in`.

Comment: In HTML text field value for ft and in is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Within those event handlers, the value is accessible as `this.value`. `this` refers to the element the event handler is on, and `value` is the property that contains the field's current value (which isn't shown in the DOM tree itself).

Comment: i was trying to read by using selenium .getAttribute("value")) but did not get the success!!